# Scroll part of vertical inside a fixed position header

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, vertical-scrolling

I have a vertical menu inside a header. The header takes the whole width and height of the screen/window. It is also fixed on top. However when the height of the menu is bigger than that of the screen it get cuts off and I cannot scroll to see the rest of it. This does not happen when the header is not fixed but I want it to remain that way.

Here is a photo of the menu normally
[Normal menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdLfJ.jpg)

and here is a photo when cropped

[Menu cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMCtz.jpg)

Comment: use max-height with overflow:scroll in navigaton

Answer (score 0):

use **overflow-y:scroll** in css. if that is not working you should be use important .**overflow-y:scroll!important** . i hope it will be work .